# Hostname '[IP]' was not verified, works on the emulator not on actual Android device

Tags: java, android, ssl, self-signed

Running an Android application that use a client keystore against a self-signed certificate, the application runs properly on the emulator (eclipse) but trying to run it on an actual Android device, with 3g connection, fails:

```
06-16 16:15:28.638: W/System.err(2335): java.io.IOException: Hostname '111.11.11.11' was not verified
06-16 16:15:28.648: W/System.err(2335):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.verifySecureSocketHostname(HttpConnection.java:223)
06-16 16:15:28.648: W/System.err(2335):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:446)
06-16 16:15:28.658: W/System.err(2335):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
06-16 16:15:28.658: W/System.err(2335):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
06-16 16:15:28.658: W/System.err(2335):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
06-16 16:15:28.658: W/System.err(2335):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
06-16 16:15:28.658: W/System.err(2335):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
06-16 16:15:28.658: W/System.err(2335):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpsServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(HttpsServiceConnectionSE.java:124)
06-16 16:15:28.668: W/System.err(2335):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:176)
06-16 16:15:28.668: W/System.err(2335):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
06-16 16:15:28.668: W/System.err(2335):     at
...
```

Besides the Internet connection, what other thing should I check to find why it's failing?

Did not find answers on:

[Android : java.io.IOException: Hostname was not verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970428/android-java-io-ioexception-hostname-was-not-verified)
[Android SSL HostName Was Not Verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671168/android-ssl-hostname-was-not-verified)
[java.io.IOException: Hostname was not verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619781/java-io-ioexception-hostname-was-not-verified)
[Hostname was not verified ANDROID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157710/hostname-was-not-verified-android)

Comment: You're making an HTTPS connection with an IP address. Now, SSL certificates are bound to DNS hostnames and since you're not using a DNS hostname to connect, the certificate cannot be verified.

Comment: is the answer for the same question in [Android : java.io.IOException: Hostname was not verified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970428/android-java-io-ioexception-hostname-was-not-verified)

Comment: Why works on the emulator and not on the Android device?

Comment: You should post your code

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing the same issue

Comment: I really don't remember what was the solution. I think it was that the server was blocking my IP.